# file modification callbacks using c++?

Tags: c++, macos, g++, boost-filesystem

i require a callback within my code (in C++) which fires every time a particular file is modified (after a save), i am using a Mac however not Xcode, i am building my code using g++, documentation for this seems to be very limited. Does anyone have any example code which performs this functionality? Or can point me in the right direction as to where to look?

Comment: Take a look at boost filesystem library. here you've got example:http://www.highscore.de/boost/file_monitor.zip

Comment: not the same question, i need a callback within the code i am writing , not an independent program which monitors a file

Answer (score 0):

On Linux you would use `ionotify`, but OSX has [FSEvents](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/FSEvents_Ref/Reference/reference.html). It seems it will only notify you about changes to directories, it's up to you to then see if the event was about your file or not. There's a C API. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556545/fsevents-c-example) has some examples.

Comment: i am surprised about the lack of examples around, seeming it should be a solved problem

Comment: It's not a common operation. But there are examples around. Even Apple has some: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/UsingtheFSEventsFramework/UsingtheFSEventsFramework.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005289-CH4-SW4