# KQUEUE only works for folder path?

Tags: c++, macos, kqueue

I am use the code (actually copy from here[FSEvents C++ Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556545/fsevents-c-example))as following, but it can only work for a path, can not work for a file. 
I just want to monitor a specific file. How can I do that? thanks

```
#include <fcntl.h>       // for O_RDONLY
#include <stdio.h>       // for fprintf()
#include <stdlib.h>      // for EXIT_SUCCESS
#include <string.h>      // for strerror()
#include <sys/event.h>   // for kqueue() etc.
#include <unistd.h>      // for close()

int main (int argc, const char *argv[])
{
   int kq = kqueue ();
   // dir name is in argv[1], NO checks for errors here
   int dirfd = open (argv[1], O_RDONLY);

   struct kevent direvent;
    EV_SET (&direvent, dirfd, EVFILT_VNODE, EV_ADD | EV_CLEAR | EV_ENABLE,
            NOTE_WRITE, 0, (void *)argv[1]);

   kevent(kq, &direvent, 1, NULL, 0, NULL);

   // Register interest in SIGINT with the queue.  The user data
   // is NULL, which is how we'll differentiate between
   // a directory-modification event and a SIGINT-received event.
   struct kevent sigevent;
   EV_SET (&sigevent, SIGINT, EVFILT_SIGNAL, EV_ADD | EV_ENABLE, 0, 0, NULL);
   // kqueue event handling happens after the legacy API, so make
   // sure it doesn eat the signal before the kqueue can see it.
   signal (SIGINT, SIG_IGN);

   // Register the signal event.
   kevent(kq, &sigevent, 1, NULL, 0, NULL);

   while (1) {
       // camp on kevent() until something interesting happens
       struct kevent change;
       if (kevent(kq, NULL, 0, &change, 1, NULL) == -1) { exit(1); }
       // The signal event has NULL in the user data.  Check for that first.
       if (change.udata == NULL) {
           break;
       } else {
        // udata is non-null, so it's the name of the directory
        printf ("%s\n", (char*)change.udata);
       }
   }
   close (kq);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What operations on the file are being performed that you're missing?

Note that many things that write files don't open the existing file and write to it; they unlink the existing file and replace it with a new one. Because of that, `kqueue()` won't report that the file that you have open has been written to.  You can add `NOTE_DELETE` to the `fflags` to try to catch that.

Comment: yes, you are right, and I did use NOTE_DELETE(and actually one more condition NOTE_RENAME) to implement the function. And I have contacted with the author, fix "one time" issue, which is also caused by the "delete" operation. I need to add the path again.