# Polling for FSEvents from C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, fsevents

I am developing a C++ library where we have a module for file system handling and specifically callbacks for file changes. I have implemented the fsevent callback (as described in https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/FSEvents_Ref/Reference/reference.html and [FSEvents C++ Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556545/fsevents-c-example)).

The problem is that I don't get any callbacks unless i call `CFRunLoopRun()` after `FSEventStreamStart(stream)` which blocks the main thread. If I use the same code in a GLFW context without `CFRunLoopRun()` I get the callbacks and everything works fine (non-blocking).

I have gone through a lot of GLFW code and implemented an Objective-C NSEvent polling that GLFW does in its `glfwPollEvents()` function, unfortunately the event is nil every time it is called and no callbacks gets called.

GLFW snippet from cocoa_window.m:

```
for (;;)
{
    NSEvent* event = [NSApp nextEventMatchingMask:NSAnyEventMask
                                        untilDate:[NSDate distantPast]
                                           inMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                                          dequeue:YES];
    if (event == nil)
        break;

    [NSApp sendEvent:event];
}
```

Any ideas on how to get the callbacks (even if I have to poll for them) without having to run a GLFW context?

**Update:**

I would have like to get the callbacks asynchronously but I found `FSEventStreamFlushSync` that forces the callback (if there is one) to get called (and it works!). I had tried the Async version first which didn't work.

Comment: well you *need* some runloop for this to work. why cant you attach it to the main run loop? use `FSEventStreamScheduleWithRunLoop` to schedule on `CFRunLoopGetCurrent`. all of this is in the thread you linked.

Comment: sorry, I meant `CFRunLoopGetMain`.

Comment: I am using FSEventStreamScheduleWithRunLoop and tried both CFRunLoopGetCurrent and CFRunLoopGetMain. None of them seem to work without the GLFW context or the CFRunLoopRun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to use `FSEventStreamFlushSync` which forces callbacks without the GLFW context.